# Consuming/reading from a stream on demand or asynchronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, stream

I want to get chunks from stream when I need. But don't know how to do it instead of flowing. As far as I know, the usual stream is flowing from input to output, but what I want is to store stream then leak some amounts when I need until drains.

**The real code**

```js
const fs = require('fs')
let end = false

const requestChunkFrom = async (stream, size) => {
    while(1) {
        if (stream.readable){
            let data = await stream.read(size);
            if (data) return {chunk: data , isEnd: false}
        }
        if (stream.closed) return {chunk: null,  isEnd: true} 
    }
}
const job = async () => {
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('README.md')
    stream.on('end', () => {
        console.log('end')
        stream.close()
    })
    stream.on('readable', () => {
        console.log('readable')
    })
    do {
        const {chunk, isEnd} = await requestChunkFrom(stream, 16)
        end = isEnd
        console.log(chunk)
    } while (!end)
}
job()
```

I think this function would been waiting until `readable` or `closed` then return chunk, but It doesn't work as expectation.

Comment: You need to attach `readable` event on the readable stream and to get the data, you need to call `read()` method on the stream. Readable event is emitted whenever there is a chunk of data available but to pause the stream, you probably need the `data` event, not the `readable` event. [Readable streams docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#readable-streams) might help.

Comment: Thanks, But on data event, the stream is flowing. How can I demand data when I need, not the time of data filled?

Comment: Not sure how you can demand data when needed. You could try adding data event and pause the stream after required or greater than required size of chunk has been read. Then you can resume the stream again when next chunk(s) are needed. I feel like streams might not be what you need here. Maybe some other mechanism that only reads data when needed.

Comment: @Yousaf You are right. I want to consume data on demand and it looks not match with stream mechanism. Maybe it is more similar to Buffer not Stream.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all your async function doesn't have any await in it. Your `stream.read()` is returns a `Promise` so you need to await it.

```
const requestChunkFrom = async (stream, size) => {
  while(1) {
    if (stream.readable){
        let data = await stream.read(size);
        return {chunk: data , isEnd: false}
    }
    if (stream.closed) return {chunk: null,  isEnd: true} // But there might unconsumed data have left.
  }
}
```

> Try this to see if you get any results

```
stream.on('readable', async() => {
        console.log('readable')
        do {
         const {chunk, isEnd} = await 
         requestChunkFrom(stream, 16)
         end = isEnd
         console.log(chunk)
        } while (!end)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but the `data` from `stream.read(size)` is constantly `null`.
I'll modify question to reveal whole my test code. 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you get `readable` printed to the console when you run your program? If yes move your do while loop inside callback of `stream.on('readable', ...)`. I will edit my answer to see what I meant.

Comment: I cannot see `readable` console log. It seems halted in a loop.

Comment: Do you have any date in your file from where are you reading data? Have you tried console logging the stream object, maybe your filename or path is wrong. Can you post what do you get when console logging stream object.